# Unable to create the "/xls/sample.xlsx" directory

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload an xls file into a folder called "xls" in my public directory.

At first it worked when i deployed my application on the webserver but latter when i made some changes to my files although i did not touch the files partaining to uploadinging the xls.then it stopped working when i try to upload online an throews me the error "Unable to create the "/xls/sample.xlsx" directory". But it still works on my localhost if i try to upload.

I have changed the folder permission to 777 and 755.But still no luck.below is how my controller looks like

```
public function store()
    {
        $rules =[
        'xls'       => 'Required|mimes:xls,xlsx',
         ];

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

            if ($validation->passes()) 
            {
                $xls = new Xls;

                $xlsname=Input::file('xls')->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = public_path('xls/'.$xlsname); 

                $xls->name  = $xlsname;

                Input::file('xls')->move($path);

                $xls->save();

                return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','Excel Sheet successfully uploaded');

            }
            $formerror = Response::json($validation->messages()->toArray());

            // Session::put('formerror',$formerror);
     }
```

Please what am i doing wrong

EDIT ONE:

when i make the following changes to my controller it still doesnt work on my webserve it throws error :Unable to create the "/xls" directory, but works perfectly on my local host.

```
public function store()
    {
        $rules =[
        'xls'       => 'Required|mimes:xls,xlsx',
         ];

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

            if ($validation->passes()) 
            {
                $xls = new Xls;

                $xlsname=Input::file('xls')->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = public_path('xls'); 

                $xls->name  = $xlsname;

                Input::file('xls')->move($path,$xlsname);

                $xls->save();

                return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','Excel Sheet successfully uploaded');

            }
            // $formerror = Response::json($validation->messages()->toArray());

            Session::put('formerror',$validation->messages()->toArray());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files) the `move` function expects the destination path as first argument and the (optional) filename as a second. (I believe the default filename will be the one from the client). So the first parameter should be the folder and not the full path.

So instead do this:

```
$path = public_path('xls');
Input::file('xls')->move($path); // or, alternatively: ->move($path, 'your-own-file-name.xls');
```

Comment: it still trows me error "Unable to create the "/xls" directory".but when i make the changes.it works on mylocalhost but not on the webserver